# Replace string to match plural or singular

Tags: php, regex, string

can you help me with a function to replace string as following:

The string `the boo[k|ks] [is|are] on the table` will output `the book is on the table` or `the books are on the table` according to an argument.

```
<?php
    $unformated_str = "the boo[k|ks] [is|are] on the table";
    $plural = true;

    echo formatstr($unformated_str, $plural);
?>
```

Output:

```
the books are on the table
```

Forgive my poor english. I hope I made my question clear enough.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: that function doesn't exists... yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that uses [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
function formatstr( $unformatted_str, $plural) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '#\[([^\]]+)\]#i', function( $match) use ($plural) {
        $choices = explode( '|', $match[1]);
        return ( $plural) ? $choices[1] : $choices[0];
    }, $unformatted_str);
}

$unformated_str = "the boo[k|ks] [is|are] on the table";

echo formatstr($unformated_str, false); // the book is on the table
echo formatstr($unformated_str, true); // the books are on the table
```

[Try it out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/POWnG2)

Answer (score 0):

```
function plural (str, num) {// https://gist.github.com/kjantzer/4957176
    var indx = num == 1 ? 1 : 0;
    str = str.replace(/\[num\]/, num);
    str = str.replace(/{(.[^}]*)}/g, function(wholematch,firstmatch){
        var values = firstmatch.split('|');
        return values[indx] || '';
    });
    return str;
}
plural('There {are|is} [num] book{s}.', 21); //"There are 21 books."
plural('There {are|is} [num] book{s}.', 1);  //"There is 1 book.
```