# Removing specific string with jQuery - regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to remove a specific string from a piece of text using jQuery.

I used to have a piece of software called RegexBuddy to build regular expressions, but otherwise I am incompetent and useless at it.

Fortunately my question is entirely basic, I need to replace the following string, and only the following string, from a piece of text

```
[ST1]
```

Note that basically its ST followed by a number which might change, so it could be [ST12] or [ST15], these need to be removed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Replacing a value in a string is basic javascript.  It doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace string to match plural or singular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143194/replace-string-to-match-plural-or-singular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the Metacharacter `\d`:**

The global flag `g` it's important to match all occurrences.

```js
var str = "Ele[ST1]E[ST1521]le".replace(/\[ST\d+\]/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ST[0-9]+` will match all instances of ST followed by 1 or more number characters

`\[ST[0-9]+\]` will remove the brackets as well.